Question about how this implies an invariant subspace
The context of this is the proof of (part) of Schur's Lemma in Howard Georgi's Lie Algebras in particle physics.
We want to prove theorem 1.3 which states "if $D_1(g)A = AD_2(g) \forall g \in G$ where $D_1$ and $D_2$ are irreducible representations, then $A = 0$.
He starts by supposing there exists a $\mu$ such that $A\mu = 0$. Then, there is a non-zero-projector $P$ that annihilates $A$ on the right. Let's call the subspace $S$. Up to here, it makes sense to me. Then, he uses this and the assumption to say $AD_2(g)P = 0$. Makes sense. He states that this implies $S$ is invarinat with respect to representation $D_2$.
Question: how does $AD_2P = 0 (\forall g)$ imply that the subspace $S$ is an invariant subspace of $D_2$? Couldn't there be some vector such that $D_2Pv\neq 0$ but $AD_2Pv=0$
Possible attempt (doesn't answer question but completes proof): We use $AD_2P = 0 =APD_2P \implies A(PD_2P-D_2P) =0$ which means that either $PD_2P=D_2P$ or $A=0$. Since $D_2$ cannot have an invariant subspace (its irreducible), then $A=0$.

I checked the book, and $P$ is not just any projector that annihilates $A$; it is the projection onto the subspace $K = \{v : Av = 0\}$. Do you see why $AD_2(g)P = 0$ for all $g$ implies $K$ is invariant?
